# Help with XML, PHP and CDATA

Tags: php, html, xml, cdata

I have the following contents in my XML file:

```
<items>
<item id="1"><content><![CDATA[<p>string</p>]]></content></item>
</items>
```

I have HTML inside the content, so, I used CDATA. However, when I'm trying to display the content as HTML on the web page:

```
$item_content = $xpath2->query("/bulletin/item[@id='$item_id']/content");
foreach ($item_content as $i)
{
    $a = $dom->createElement('div');
    $a->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection($i->nodeValue));
    // $child = $dom->createElement('div',$i->nodeValue); <--this fails miserably
    $content_tag->appendChild($a);
}
```

It will get displayed as:

&lt ;p&gt ;string&lt ;/p&gt ;

How do I display it as HTML?

Comment: Why are you using DOM to output HTML in php? Why not just echo it out directly as in `echo $i->nodeValue` ?

Comment: I have to modify an existing app... I'll see what I can do about that echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $a->appendChild($i->nodeValue);
```

instead of having:

```
$a->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection($i->nodeValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

With [html_ entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), it's possible to convert the html entities to normal characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the html_entity_decode() function.